# VirtualBox - can I clone a snapshot?

Tags: windows-7, clone, virtual-machine, virtualbox, snapshot

I have a VirtualBox VM machine and I took a few snapshots.

VirtualBox works on a Window7 x64 and plays a Window7 x64 system as well.
Now I would like to clone the very first snapshot but I would prefer to do it without restoring it.

If I right click any snapshot I have this Clone command but I am not sure that if I select the first snapshot I will get a clone of that particular snapshot or the current state will be cloned?

Yes, I could try and see what happens but it would kill my HDD and thrash my free space and time...
Found no clear docs so far.

Comment: Can I get an explanation why this question has been voted for closing?

Comment: @Adi - Couldn't you easily verify what happens when you clone it?  Create a snapshot, with a specific change, then clone the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in your particular VM's snapshot menu you can restore any snapshot to be the currently active one and then create the clone from that restored snapshot.

Can't post a screenshot but if you highlight the snapshot name and then click the button with the red up arrow or hit ctrl+shift+r you'll restore the snapshot.