# Export a VM with the snapshots?

Tags: virtualbox, export, snapshot

I have a machine with snapshots at different key points in the configuration.
Now I need to back up this VM, with its snapshots, to another machine.

- I tried the "Export" function, but the .ova file only contain the Current state, no snapshots.
- Other solution I see is reverting to the first snapshot, export, forward to the next snapshot, export... It would be long, tedious, and heavy.

Is there any ways to take a VM and send it to another computer while preserving the snapshots?

Comment: Typically the way you export a virtual machine with snapshots is to clone the virtual machine and this will generate a new consolated virtual machine.  Have you tried to clone the virtual machine?

Comment: [VirtualBox - can I clone a snapshot?](http://superuser.com/questions/502118/virtualbox-can-i-clone-a-snapshot)

Comment: @Ramhound: I do can clone the VM, but it stay on the same machine, I need to pass the file to another computer. Unless I missed a option to clone to a file? I also need all snapshots, not just one of them. The goal is also archiveing.

Comment: @Ramhound: Edited to explain in details the use case, and my current solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To copy an entire VM with its snapshots and everything, the only way I know of
is by copying the entire folder of the VM.
Zipping the folder with 7z will reduce the disk-space to transfer.

If required, the VM *with its snapshots* can be cloned under another name by:

> [right-click] VM -> **Clone**... -> [button] **Next** -> [radio
>   button] **Full clone** -> [radio button] **Everything** -> [button]
>   **Clone**

See the article [Moving A VirtualBox VM With Snapshots](https://ehikioya.com/moving-virtualbox-vm-snapshots/)
for a detailed write-up.

Answer (score 1):

The process of copying the full "Virtual VMs" folder from one host to another may be summarized as follows:

Backup:
     Backup full “c:/Users/oldlogname/Virtual Vms” folder

Restore:

- Restore full “c:/Users/newlogname/Virtual Vms” folder
- Edit each “*.vbox-prev”  file of each VM, replacing affected paths/lognames
- Start VirtualBox console in new host

  - Menu: Machine->Add … (each one of the imported VM folder/vmfile)
  - Declare and associate shared folders existing in the old vm host
- Update “virtualbox additions” to each VM if the host VBox has different version

Enjoy.